# Are there any countries with laws that require maximizing profits?

Tags: law, economy, capitalism

It is a common trope I see claimed quite often similar to:

> Individuals and interest groups are governed by laws that demand
>   maximum profit where possible. These laws are inherent in the monetary
>   system prevalent in most countries today – capitalism.

[SOURCE](https://www.thevenusproject.com/resource-based-economy/)

or here

> It also makes no sense to endlessly chase after individual instances
>   of corporate wrongdoing, when that wrongdoing is a natural result of
>   the system design. Corporations abuse the public interest because the
>   law tells them their only legal duty is to maximize profits for
>   shareholders. Until we change the law of corporate governance, the
>   problem of corporate abuse can never fully be solved.

[SOURCE](http://www.commondreams.org/views02/0119-04.htm) (final paragraph)

Or Senator Al Franken

> In a recent speech at the Netroots Nation, Senator Al Franken tried to
>   frighten the crowd by trotting out the corporate bogeyman that
>   greedily makes decisions without regard to anything other than profit.
>   Franken told them: “it is literally malfeasance for a corporation not
>   to do everything it legally can to maximize its profits.”

[SOURCE](http://www.litigationandtrial.com/2010/09/articles/series/special-comment/ebay-v-newmark-al-franken-was-right-corporations-are-legally-required-to-maximize-profits/)

I am aware of no law in the US or any other country that requires anything like this.  I know that it is a common business goal to improve profitability but rarely see a reputable company that takes an increase profits at all cost philosophy.

So are there any laws in the US or any other 1st world country with similar requirements?

Comment: This may be an understanding issue; the paragraph doesn't reference an actual law, instead negatively pointing at the concept of Capitalism, specifically "Make Money."

Comment: @DrunkCynic - That is not what it says though "are governed by laws that demand maximum profit where possible" I hear this quite a bit from the anti-capitolists but I know of no laws that encourage this behavior directly, and of no companies that are run with this overt mentality.  Even where it has existed in places like Enron, and Lehman Brothers, it was done covertly among a small class of important people who knew they were at best operating in the grey areas of the law, and often on the wrong side of it.

Comment: Consider the Laws of Gravity and the Laws of Thermodynamics.

Comment: (-1) This question seems like a bad pun. The claim, however vacuous or questionable it might be, is clearly not about a written statute but about laws in the sense of principles of (social) behaviour.

Comment: I updated the question with more claims of the same thing.

Comment: Surely this fits better on skeptics.SE than on politics.SE?

Comment: @AndyT - I am more interested in the political aspect of if there are any countries that actually require that which would be off topic there.

Comment: Shareholder automatically maximize profit or return of investor. That is law of nature. Is there a law in the country that telling managers to do so? There is. But even without such laws, investors would simply buy stocks that are governed efficiently.

Comment: @J.Chang - If there is then you should be able to cite that law in an answer...  And yes people sell stocks when their board or officers do things that they disagree with or think will negatively impact the stock long term. It is not illegal to make a bad choice.

Answer (score 5):

It derives from the [fiduciary duty](http://www.inc.com/encyclopedia/fiduciary-duty.html) of managers. From the link:

> Corporate directors have a special fiduciary duty to their shareholders. They are accountable not only for the safekeeping of assets but also for their efficient and effective use.

"Efficient and effective use" means that the manager has to do what is best for shareholders, increasing the value of their assets (note that this may not always mean direct monetary value; a manager can claim that donating to a charity improves the public perception of the business even if it cost money short term).

And yes, a manager can be sued if they fail in performing their fiduciary duty (although proving it is hard unless the case involves embezzlement or fraud).

Also

`rarely see a reputable company that takes an increase profits at all cost philosophy.`

What you rarely see is a reputable company **publicly admitting** that. Which is OK, because the manager saying "all my company cares is about profits" could cause a negative reaction of the public, thus being of breach of the above mentioned fiduciary duty. So they instead they say that they talk about caring about the customers (and that somehow the profits they get are an unexpected bonus...).

As Scott Adams wrote in one of his books, if they care most about their customers or employees, why do they treat them the way they do? Look at pharma companies for more info.

Comment: That is not the same as maximizing profit though.  Often maximizing profit would be at the expense of share price.  The question is not do companies operate in the best interests of the public at all times just do they have an obligation to *MAXIMIZE PROFITS*

Comment: What part of "efficient and effective use" don't you understand? If a fiduciary can get 100$ to his entrustor and only gets him 40$, then he is not being "efficient and effective" by any means.

Comment: Prove that then...  Your assumption that your statement is true does not mean it is true.

Comment: Prove what? It is a **definition** of efficient, definitions do not have proofs; go and search a dictionary. Note that profit is not the same that dividend, a company that provides no dividend because it reinvests its profits is also giving profit to the shareholder because the stock value raises to match the increased value of the company.

Comment: If you spend 10k on stock and I as the CEO can get you $1k in dividend but the result would be there is no operating capitol and the company goes out of business then my getting you $1k instead of $100 was definately not more efficient and effective.

Comment: Why do you ask questions if you do not read the answers? I already explained very clearly that profit comes not from dividends alone but from the sum of dividends and the value of the stock (which in turn depends of the value of the company). And a manager cooking the books to provide an unrealistic dividend and dooming the business has happenned before and is certainly punishable (it is just a variation of Ponzi schemes)

Comment: @Chad - if the manager knowingly ruined the business pursuing short term profits, he violated fiduciary duty. The problem is, *proving* it is extremely difficult if not impossible in court of law, because what you need to prove is that he *knew* that would be the outcome, as opposed that he simply made a "mistake". The latter means you can't convict them. (a side story is, that if corporate governance worked correctly, said CEO would have been booted out of a job by the BOD)

Comment: @Chad Do you mean short-term profits or profits over a given period of time like one year? Because otherwise I don't understand your objections. The obligation is to maximize profit *over the whole lifetime of the company*, that's how profits, dividends, share price, shareholder's interests, and fiduciary duty are connected and that's what the critics you found have in mind. People disagree on whether that's a good thing overall or whether there is any workable alternative but there is nothing really controversial here. That's how capitalism works.

Comment: @Relaxed - I want to see references to laws that require the maximization of profits.   I disagree that maximizing profits over any period of time is the same as "efficient and effective use" of corporate assets unless there is some reference that backs up that requirement *LEGALLY*

Comment: @Chad It has been pointed out that the quote you provided weren't about legality in the first place. But ignoring that for a moment, what do you suppose "efficient and effective use" means then? What other interests do shareholders have? You won't find any reference spelling that out more explicitly because there is no need to: that's crystal clear to anybody who is not deliberately being obtuse. As user4012 already explained, your attempt to show that it's not what fiduciary duty is about is a non-sequitur, based on the confusion between short-term profits and profit in general.

Comment: @Relaxed _ I do not know what it means in this context.  Perhaps if the answer was updated to show what it means legally....  You know what I have been asking for